# Cute Report Test Fail

Tags: qt

I'm testing a Cute report writer, working with QT. My problem is that when i add the include directory to the .pro file i get the following error:

```
11:50:41: Running steps for project ReportTest...
11:50:41: Starting: "C:\Qt\5.9.1\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" C:\Users\dkolb\Documents\Develop\test\ReportTest\ReportTest.pro -spec win32-g++
Info: creating stash file C:\Users\dkolb\Documents\Develop\test\build-ReportTest-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MinGW_32bit-Release\.qmake.stash
11:50:44: The process "C:\Qt\5.9.1\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
11:50:44: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" qmake_all
mingw32-make: Nothing to be done for 'qmake_all'.
11:50:48: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
11:50:48: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/dkolb/Documents/Develop/test/build-ReportTest-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MinGW_32bit-Release'
'C:\Qt\5.9.1\mingw53_32\bin\uic.exe' ../ReportTest/mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wextra -Wall -W -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I../ReportTest -I. -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/ExaroLogic/CuteReport/development/include/cutereport" -IC:/Qt/5.9.1/mingw53_32/include -IC:/Qt/5.9.1/mingw53_32/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/5.9.1/mingw53_32/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/5.9.1/mingw53_32/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/5.9.1/mingw53_32/include/QtCore -Irelease -I. -IC:/Qt/5.9.1/mingw53_32/mkspecs/win32-g++  -o release/main.o ../ReportTest/main.cpp
Makefile.Release:346: recipe for target 'release/main.o' failed
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/dkolb/Documents/Develop/test/build-ReportTest-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MinGW_32bit-Release'
Makefile:36: recipe for target 'release' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release/main.o] Error -1073741502
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2
11:50:58: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project ReportTest (kit: Desktop Qt 5.9.1 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step "Make"
11:50:58: Elapsed time: 00:17.
```

For testing I'm using an empty gui application.It does compile when i take the include out.
I have download the 32bit version of the report writer as i'm compiling on 32bits, but i don't think that QT is even near the dlls. Here is the .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = ReportTest
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files (x86)/ExaroLogic/CuteReport/development/include/cutereport"

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui
```

Comment: You lack the libs statement

Comment: I had them and i got the problem. I started to test line by line. Would the include path trigger an action somewhere else? That tells me for example i could not add C:Temp to the include path?